# different level directory pointing in PHP

Tags: php, html, directory, include-path

I am building a PHP data driven site and I'm having some problems with my directory pointing.

I have an index file that works well:

**`index.php`**

```
   <?php
include'inc/header.php';
include'inc/navigation.php';
include'inc/mysql_con_links.php';
?>
```

Then in my folder `inc/` I have many files but the one that is casing the problem is `list_item.php`.

In this file I once again include `mysql_con_links.php` and it correctly calls the right piece of code that generates a list new bands added.

The problem is when I click on a new band on any other page except `index.php` in does not load the correct directory, for example once I click on it from `index.php` I get

```
http://stuweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~ob219/bookingsystem/inc/list_item.php?id=14
```

perfect.

But when I click on a band in the link

```
http://stuweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~ob219/bookingsystem/inc/list_item.php?id=14
```

(as I have included `mysql_con_links.php` in `list_item.php`) I get

```
http://stuweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~ob219/bookingsystem/inc/inc/list_item.php?id=14
```

so there is a problem with how I've called the directory.

**`list_item.php`**

```
<?php
include'navigation.php';
include 'mysql_con_links.php';
include 'library/connect.php';

$Band_id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Bands WHERE Band_id = $Band_id");

//var_dump($Band_id);
//var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($result));
echo "<table border = '1'><tr><th>Band Name</th><th>Venue</th><th>Category</th><th>Stock</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) // !!!problem here!!!
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Venue']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Category']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
    include 'library/close.php';

?>
```

I am rather new to PHP so the syntax of my code my not be perfect so any pointers as well as the problem I am having would be appreciated.

Link to current site: http://stuweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~ob219/bookingsystem/

Comment: in your case I'd suggest you use absolute full address

Comment: I have tried this, it just says cant find if I use full directory.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] then plus your rest subfolder?

Comment: Ok so like $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] include 'mysql_con_links.php' ;  ?

Comment: I have just take a further look at your page, there are some improvements you could do. First, your band names are wrapped in many unordered lists, while you could use only one and put the band names in each <li>, not a <ul> for each name. Secondly, you may not need to change your include path, but change your <a> tag href attributes.

Comment: thank you, I understand the part about li and ul but could you elaborate more on the links ?

Comment: I believe you wrap your brand names with a <a> tag, don't you? In that <a> tag is where you specify the hyper-link for click (something like href="inc/list_item.php?id=XX", look at that link and change it to an absolute address would be the easiest way for you.